# Class involving actionListener not being abstract

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Events1 extends JFrame {

  private JLabel label;
  private JButton button;

  public Events1() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    label = new JLabel("");


    button = new JButton("Click for text");

    add(button);
    add(label);

    event e = new event();
    button.addActionListener(e);
  }

    public class event implements ActionListener {

      public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setText("See motherfucker it does do stuff");
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Events1 window = new Events1();
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      window.setSize(500, 500); //.pack();
      window.setVisible(true);
      window.setTitle("Attempt 2");

    }

}
```

Basically I'm new to GUI's and get the error message when I try to compile the above code:

```
Events1.java:25: error: Events1.event is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
    public class event implements ActionListener {
           ^
1 error
```

I basically made this code based on the information on the Oracle Docs and and pretty confused of why this doesn't work/how to fix it.

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in overriden method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

That's why you should use @Override annotation for overriden methods and IDE support for this kind of operations.